# Accessing Groovy properties or methods

Tags: groovy

I have a simple question. If I have an `HttpResponseDecorator`(`groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator`) how come I can do `response.status` to get the response code? When I'm debugging I don't see this property available in the object. I looked up the API and I don't see the status property available. How is `response.status` working? Am I missing a language feature?

Comment: It has a getStatus() method.

Comment: I see that, but how does groovy automatically correspond .status with .getStatus()? Because there is also a getStatusLine() method.

Comment: When you access `response.status`, the Groovy compiler will make your statement call `response.getStatus()`. Similarly, you can call `response.getStatusLine()` by accessing `response.statusLine`. This is a fundamental part of the Groovy syntax. Read all about it at http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I'd put that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Groovy property is a combination of a private field and getters/setters.
Groovy will then generate the getters/setters appropriately.

For example:

```
class Person {
    String name                             
    int age
}
```

Properties are accessed by name and will call the getter or setter transparently.
I would recommend read more in the [Groovy documentation for field and properties](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_fields_and_properties).